# SBT build with reference on private git repo fails

Tags: git, scala, sbt

I decided to split a huge SBT multi module project on multiple git repositories. All of the repositories are hosted in private repos.

When I use such a line in `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val common = ProjectRef(uri("git://github.com:PRIVATE-ORG/akka-common.git"), "akka-common")
```

SBT throws an error:

```
fatal: Unable to look up github.com:PRIVATE-ORG (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

I try to run the SBT build on local machine where I have access to these private repos.

**UPDATE**

I tried to change a protocol:

```
lazy val common = ProjectRef(uri("ssh://git@github.com:PRIVATE-ORG/akka-common.git"), "akka-common")
```

The error is changed:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How to deal with issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by 2 steps:

1. Change format of `uri` in `ProjectRef`:

```
lazy val common = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/PRIVATE-ORG/akka-common.git"), "common")
```

2. [Adding of GitHub ssh key to the ssh agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)

After these steps everything started work as expected!